# passing variable from url to CreateView

Tags: django

I am looking for a way to automatically fill in the ForeignField ID based on the url. The user will click a link, pointing to the CreateView with the id of the ForeignField added to the end of it. I am unsure of the best way of doing this.

urls.py

```
url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', CommentCreate.as_view()),
```

views.py

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = CommentCreateForm
    model = Comment
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
```

html-link.html

```
<a href="/comment/{{ artical.id }}">Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `queryset` is invalid for `CreateView`. Of course you can set it, but it does not make a sense, because when you use `CreateView` it is supposed that you want to create an object.

I guess you can try something like:

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = CommentCreateForm
    model = Comment
    form_class = FollowupForm

    def get_form(self):
        form = super(CommentCreate, self).get_form(self.form_class)
        # artical_id - is a name of foreign key defined the Comment model.
        form.instance.artical_id = Artical.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk', None))
        return form
```

Answer (score 0):

That way you can spend the article in the context also

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['artical'] = Artical.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs[artical_id])
    return context
```

It can be corrected by doing filter like this:

```
context['artical'] = Artical.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs[artical_id])
```

Answer (score -2):

It is more suggestive if your url is like this:

```
#urls.py
url(r'^comment/(?P<artical_id>[0-9]+)/$', CommentCreate.as_view()),

#views.py
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = CommentCreateForm
    model = Comment
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    #That way you can spend the article in the context also
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['artical'] = Artical.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs[artical_id])
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting article_id is not defined?

Comment: It is set on your urls.py. But as pk.

Comment: I did this and cannot access the variable I set in the url at all.  This is very similar to my case except I do not have a queryset. @PuamDias